# Problem passing method as parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to write a convenience method that returns a `UIButton` and takes a title, CGRect and an action as parameters.  My code compiles and runs, but crashes when I actually click the button.

Here is my convenience method:

```
+ (UIButton *)makeButton:(NSString *)title withRect:(CGRect)rect 
        withAction:(SEL)selectorX  {

    // setup button properties
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = rect;
    [btn setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    btn.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_21.png"]
        stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0                                                                                    
        topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTitle:@"TEST" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(selectorX:) 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return btn;
}
```

And here is how I'm calling it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    btn = [Utilities makeButton:@"TEST" withRect:CGRectMake(10, 100, 236, 45) 
            withAction:@selector(buttonActionTEST:)];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

- (void) buttonActionTEST:(id)sender {

     [Utilities alert:@"yo yo yeoman"];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide both a *target* and a *selector* to call on that target. You're only providing the selector, and then do this:

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(selectorX:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

That's wrong on two accounts: first, *self* in this context evaluates to the class `Utilities` (not even an instance, but the Class object). And then, your attempt to provide the selector is also wrong as you pass a hardcoded selector `selectorX:` and not the variable with the almost-same name. It should be done like this:

```
+ (UIButton *)makeButton:(NSString *)title withRect:(CGRect)rect 
        target:(id)aTarget action:(SEL)anAction  {
...
    [btn addTarget:aTarget action:anAction 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...
}
```

and then you call it like this:

```
btn = [Utilities makeButton:@"TEST" withRect:CGRectMake(10, 100, 236, 45) 
        target:self action:@selector(buttonActionTEST:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your convenience method already takes a selector as a parameter -- it is truly a selector, so near the bottom of that method use:

```
[btn addTarget:self action:selectorX forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

(no need to wrap selectorX in @selector() as it *is* a selector).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is coming from the line:

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(selectorX:)       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Wouldn't "self" there be the Utilities class?  Also I don't think you need the @selector there.